# Is summing faster than multiplying?

Tags: c++, performance, cpu, addition, multiplication

I wonder whether a sum is faster than a product on recent CPUS. Computing a sum is mathematically easier but there might are optimizations to speed up multiplying in the processor; I don't know.

In my case, I want to combine two levels of noise and apply a threshold to them. I could simply multiply them since they are in the range from `0` to `1` and  apply a threshold in the same range. Or I could add them together and apply a threshold somewhere in the range from `0` to `2`. I know that the algorithms are not identical, but both would fulfill my requirements.

Comment: Are you saying that your code is too slow because you're multiplying instead of summing or that this is a hypothetical question and you have not yet written any code?

Comment: This is one of those situations where you should first determine whether you even need to know which one is faster, and if you do, profile both in a realistic running scenario.

Comment: I tried both and both are fast enough. Even though I asked this question, just for interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it we're talking floating point here, rather than integer operations, since you mention range of 0 to 1.

In which case, there isn't a dramatic difference. Exactly how much difference there is, depends on the actual processor the code runs on, the exact sequenece of operations (does one operation depend on another, where the answer isn't "ready" until a bit later, etc, where another algorithm allows more of the calculation to be done in parallel). So you will need to actually implement the two versions of code and measure the difference on your system. If this is something to run on many different machines, you will need to measure it on several types of machines with different processors.

This of course assumes that it's really that critical to be "fast". How long does it take, and is there a limit of how long you are "allowed" to take.

Answer (score 2):

The standard answer to optimization questions:

Make your implementation correct and readable first. Then check if that delivers acceptable performance. If it doesn't, profile your code and check where you lose most of the processing time. Then change exactly that.

You might need to change the readable code for the second step but since you made it correct and readable first you have a baseline to compare against and you can read what the code does first.

Answer (score 2):

Typical (it varies from processor to processor) numbers for x86 are

```
        Latency 1/Throughput
fp add:    3         1
fp mul:    5         1-3
int add:   1         < 1
int mul:   3-7       1-4
```

Integers with more bits are slower to multiply, and a double-width multiplication (not expressible in C) is slower yet.

The big difference between int add and int mul doesn't mean that you should write `a+a` (or `a << 1`) instead of `a*2`, the source is not (directly) what determines the performance, the resulting machine code does, and all serious compilers will do strength reduction anyway.

Comment: C: `int factor1 = 6, factor2 = -9; long product = (long)factor1 * factor2;` (hm. Assumes sizeof long > sizeof int (even sizeof long >= 2 * sizeof int), while the book said sizeof long >= sizeof int.)

Comment: @greybeard even when it works (which as you note it isn't guaranteed to), it would just be an upcast followed by a regular multiplication, not a multiplication that gives a result twice as wide as its operand type - though a Sufficiently Smart Compiler might recognize the pattern and use it anyway, it's not what the code literally says.